# ¿Como hacer uso de archivos externos de propiedades desde un proyecto WAR?

Tags: spring-boot, ansible, jboss-eap

Estoy trabajando con despliegues de archivos war en jboss,ahora requiero desplegar esos war con archivos extension properties por aparte es decir(de un lado tener el war y del otro los archivos . properties).

1._ Por lo que he investigado el WAr como tal se coloca en
**standalone/deployments/** en jboss

2._ y en (configuration) a nivel de **standalone**  los archivos properties

En el proyecto de spring boot antes de generar el WAR,  en que parte de la estructura
del proyecto ó a nivel de codigo(ejemplo) se hace referencia al uso de esos
archivos properties.

Espero puedan ayudarme con un ejemplo de codigo.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: 1._ Quisiera saber como realizar un proyecto web en spring boot en el que utilice **archivos de propiedades** y que estos estén fuera del proyecto,                                                                     2._ Despues **desplegar el WAR del proyecto y los archivos de propiedades por separado en jboss**, Cabe mencionar que los archivos de propiedades hasta donde tengo entendido solo se colocan en la ruta **$JBOSS_HOME/config**   y el WAR compilado automáticamente evocara todos los archivos de propiedades